# How to get element without element id?

Tags: javascript

```
1.<input id="kw1"></input>

2.<input></input>
```

The first one, I can use `document.getElementById` to get the object, but on some websites, like the second, there is no id in element, but I also want to get the object. How can I do this ? And do not use JQuery

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` gives array of input elements.

Comment: If you want to match that specific element, you will need *something* to distinguish it from the others. Either a matchable ancestor element (by id or class, for instance), or the index of that `<input>` element relative to the other elements of the same type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: How strange that the DOM was designed with no inherent identification, no serial number, for each node. Was this to save a little space? Nodes have forward and backward links, so saving space was not a primary concern. Was it, then, an oversight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this by using :

`getElementsByTagName`

example :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); // returns array
```

for more broader details in using it click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: if he will not dynamically generate any element, `document.querySelectorAll('input')` is considerable.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` can match dynamically-added elements.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) says differently. or did i get it wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the "non-live nodelist"? That means the returned node list will not automatically reflect further changes in the DOM. However, all the matching elements at the time of the call are returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` instead.

It'll return you an array with **every** `input`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.getElementsByTagName('input'), but this give you all input elements.

But since you have nothing else to identify that element, you can not be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

which will return a list of objects of type "input"